# Creating an instance of an object using Scala combinator parsing

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I have this parser:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class RequestMappingParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def requestMapping: Parser[Any] = "@RequestMapping(" ~ commaDelimitedSeq ~ ")"
  def commaDelimitedSeq: Parser[Any] = repsep(keyValue, ",")
  def keyValue: Parser[Any] = key ~ "=" ~ value
  def key: Parser[Any] = "value" | "method"
  def value: Parser[Any] = """[^)]*""".r
}
```

I have this simple class:

```
class MethodRequestMapping(val value: String, val method: String)
```

My parser can parse this string:

```
"@RequestMapping(value = \"/ex/foos\", method = RequestMethod.GET)"
```

and return a result of `Parser[Any]`.  I would like it to return a result of `Parser[MethodRequestMapping]`.

How do I do this?  I know I have to do something like this:

```
def requestMapping: Parser[MethodRequestMapping] = "@RequestMapping(" ~ commaDelimitedSeq ~ ")" ^^ {
  // Some sort of pattern matching and creation of MethodRequestMapping
  // ???
}
```

But what goes in the ????  Or is it better to do it some entirely different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, half the combinatorics you use are created as `Parser[String]`, and it's your type annotation that upcast them to `Parser[Any]` (which is allowed because of covariance, but also completely useless in this case).

So you actually have something like:

```
class RequestMappingParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def requestMapping: Parser[String ~ List[String ~ String ~ String] ~ String] = "@RequestMapping(" ~ commaDelimitedSeq ~ ")"
  def commaDelimitedSeq: Parser[List[String ~ String ~ String]] = repsep(keyValue, ",")
  def keyValue: Parser[String ~ String ~ String] = key ~ "=" ~ value
  def key: Parser[String] = "value" | "method"
  def value: Parser[String] = """[^)]*""".r
}
```

Then we could use `map` or `^^` to adjust types - before it was difficult because we had `Any` there, but if we won't get rid of type, we will be able to pattern-match easily

```
class RequestMappingParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  // result of this parser will be ethier "value" or "method"
  def key: Parser[String] = "value" | "method"
  def value: Parser[String] = """[^),]*""".r // you had an error here, you were missing "," to separate items
  // here we'll map String ~ String ~ String to tuple - we'll drop unused "=" in the process
  def keyValue: Parser[(String, String)] = (key ~ "=" ~ value).map {
    case k ~ _ ~ v => k -> v
  }
  // repsep wil return List[(String, String)], which we'll map to Map
  def commaDelimitedSeq: Parser[Map[String, String]] = repsep(keyValue, ",").map(_.toMap)
  // this would give us String ~ Map[String, String] ~ String, but we don't need
  // these String constants. Also we can map things into out final result
  def requestMapping: Parser[MethodRequestMapping] = ("@RequestMapping(" ~ commaDelimitedSeq ~ ")").map {
    case _ ~ map ~ _ =>
      new MethodRequestMapping(value = map("value"), method = map("method"))
  }
}
```

```
val parser = new RequestMappingParser()
val parsed = "@RequestMapping(value = \"/ex/foos\", method = RequestMethod.GET)"
val result = parser.parse(parser.requestMapping, parsed).get
// result.value == "\"/ex/foos\""
// result.method == "RequestMethod.GET"
```

That said - this parser combinations library is discouraged, mostly because of being slow. For production it is suggested to use something like [FastParse](https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/), which has faster implementation and more features.